# Как убрать вибрацию, при JavaScript анимации?

Tags: javascript, анимация

Есть вот такая бесконечная рекурсивная анимация, где движутся изначально прописанные элементы, а потом начинают генерироватся элементы и тоже двигаться.

Проблема - как убрать эффект вибрации, который наиболее сильно появляется на вновь сгенерированных элементах?

```js
function deltaTop(progress) {
    return progress;
}
function deltaLeft(progress) {
    return progress*0.88;
}

window.onload = function(){
 var newProduct = document.getElementsByClassName('combainer-element');
 for(var i = 0; i < newProduct.length; i++){
  var start = Date.now();
  animation(newProduct[i],start);
 }

var v8 = 'v8';
 var twlk = 'twlk';
 var payforme = 'payforme';
 var flag = 1;
 setInterval(function() {
  if(flag == 1){
   var start = Date.now();
   animationNew(v8,start);
   flag = 2;
   delElement();
  } else if(flag == 2){
   var start = Date.now();
   animationNew(twlk,start);
   flag = 3;
   delElement();
  }else if(flag == 3){
   var start = Date.now();
   animationNew(payforme,start);
   flag = 1;
   delElement();
  }
 }, 1700);
};

 function animationNew(project, start) {
  //Создаем элемент
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.setAttribute('class','combainer-element element0 '+project);
  container = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
  container.insertBefore(elem, container.children[0]);

  var topPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
  var leftPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  //Анимируем перемещение элемента
  var from = leftPosition; 
  var from2 = topPosition;
  var to = leftPosition + 2200;
  var to2 = topPosition - 1200;
  var duration = 19999;

  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      var now = Date.now() - start;
      var progress = now / duration;
      var result = (to - from) * deltaLeft(progress) + from;
      var result2 = (to2 - from2) * deltaTop(progress) + from2;
      elem.style.left = result + "px";
      elem.style.top = result2 + "px";
      if (progress < 1){
       requestAnimationFrame(arguments.callee, 1000/60);
      } else{
      }
  }, 1000/60);
 };

 function animation(elem, start) {
  var topPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
  var leftPosition = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  //Анимируем перемещение элемента
  var from = leftPosition; 
  var from2 = topPosition;
  var to = leftPosition + 2200;
  var to2 = topPosition - 1200;
  var duration = 19999;

  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      var now = Date.now() - start;
      var progress = now / duration;
      var result = (to - from) * deltaLeft(progress) + from;
      var result2 = (to2 - from2) * deltaTop(progress) + from2;
      elem.style.left = result + "px";
      elem.style.top = result2 + "px";

      if (progress < 1){
       requestAnimationFrame(arguments.callee, 1000/60);
      } else{
      }
  }, 1000/60);
 };

function delElement(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('combainer-element');
  var endElem = elem.length;
  elem[endElem-1].remove();
 }
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.combainer-element {
 position:absolute;
 width:380px;
 height:233px; 
}
.element0{
       top:950px;
       left:-50px;
}
.element1{
       top:850px;
       left:100px;
}
.element2{
       top:750px;
       left:250px;
}
.element3{
       top:650px;
       left:400px;
}
.element4{
       top:550px;
       left:550px;
}
.element5{
       top:450px;
       left:700px;
}
.element6{
       top:350px;
       left:850px;
}
.element7{
       top:250px;
       left:1000px;
}
.element8{
       top:150px;
       left:1150px;
}
.element9{
        top: 50px;
     left: 1300px;
}
.element10{
        top: -50px;
     left: 1450px;
}
.element11{
        top: -150px;
     left: 1600px;
}
.twlk{
    background-color: red;
}
.payforme{
    background-color:blue; 
}
.v8{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="combainer-element element0 v8"></div> 
 <div class="combainer-element element1 twlk"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element2 payforme"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element3 v8"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element4 twlk"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element5 payforme"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element6 v8"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element7 twlk"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element8 payforme"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element9 v8"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element10 twlk"></div>
 <div class="combainer-element element11 payforme"></div>
</main>
```

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Greyewi/pen/ORgWOE)

Comment: Попробуйте анимировать элементы не через свойства left и top, а через transform + ознакомьтесь со свойством will-change: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/will-change